# Need help on understanding the proof for the theorem related to closed set and cluster points.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem 8.2.3** *A subset S of a normed vector space V is closed if and only if every cluster point **p** of S is an element of S.*

*Proof:* Suppose first that $S$ is closed. Let $\mathbf{p}$ be any cluster point of $S$. We need to prove that $\mathbf{p}\in S$. By hypothesis, there is a sequence $\mathbf{x}^{(j)}\to\mathbf{p}$ as $j\to\infty$.

> Thus for every open ball $B_r(\mathbf{p})$ there exists
>   $J\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $j\geq J \implies \mathbf{x}^{(j)}\in
>  B_r(\mathbf{p})$. Thus $\mathbf{p} \not\in S^c = V \setminus S$ since
>   the latter set is open.

Hence $\mathbf{p}\in S$. $\blacksquare$

I boxed the part I didn't understand. I can see that for any small open ball, I can let the sequence of the vectors to be in that open ball if I go far out enough in the sequence. But I don't really understand how that leads to  "$\mathbf{p} \not\in S^c = V \setminus S$ since
 the latter set is open." From my understanding, I think it must be true that $\mathbf{p}\in S$ since I can make $\mathbf{p}$ really close to an element that is in $S$. But how does $S^c$ being open implies that this is true? Can someone fill in the details that led to this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $G$ is said to be **open** if for every $p \in G$ there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}(p) \subset G$.

In your case, were $p \in S^c$, we could find a sufficiently small ball $B_{\epsilon}(p) \subset S^c$.  But since $x^n \to p$, if $n$ is sufficiently large then $x^n \in B_{\epsilon} \subset S^c$, which is a contradiction.